# Why does calling pp pp not loop?

Tags: ruby

If I assign a value to the variable `pp` and then call `pp pp` in the console why doesn't pretty print loop?

```
$ irb

pp = "hello world"
=> "hello world" 
pp pp
"hello world"
=> "hello world"
```

According to this explanation I think it should

https://blog.brycekerley.net/2014/08/27/Working-with-pp-the-Ruby-Pretty-Printer.html

Edit: I didn't mean that it must loop, I just wanted to know the method call order that happened that prevented it from looping.

Comment: There is a big disclaimer at the top of that web page, saying **"This post is pretty old! Opinions and technical information in it are almost certainly outdated. Commands and configurations will probably not work."**. Additionally, it's not obvious to me why `pp pp` "should" loop.

Comment: Could you explain why you think "`pp pp` should loop"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby is an interpreted language, meaning that, instead of compiling, it executes the code as written, interpreting the code line by line, word by word (or rather token by token).

When ruby interpreter encounters a line `pp pp`, it needs to resolve two tokens. First one is clearly a method as it takes an argument, the other one can be either a method OR local variable (there are no brackets nor arguments).

So, during execution, ruby will start resolution from the second token. When it is not clear whether token denotes variable or method, **ruby always searches for variable first**. In this case, the variable is there as you assigned a value to `pp` creating a local variable (let's say by `pp = 1`).

Then ruby has still to process the second token, but now it looks like `pp(1)` (because first token has been resolved already). In this case this is, again, clearly a method so ruby just send a `pp` message to `self` (which in this context is (main) object). Method `pp` is defined on Kernel, so each object - including `(main)` can access it.

The key point here is to understand that you have not overridden method `pp` - that method is still there. The only thing that happened is different resolution of `pp` token. Even with `pp` hidden (or shadowed) by local variable, you can still invoke it either by using explicit `self.pp` or by making sure that it looks like a method `pp()`

Comment: "Ruby is an interpreted language" – There is no such thing as an "interpreted language". Interpretation and compilation are a trait of the interpreter or compiler (duh!) not the language. "interpreting the code line by line, word by word (or rather token by token)" – Interpreters that work that way haven't existed since the 1960s. Even matz's original Ruby implementation (which is no longer used) which was a pure interpreter, was an AST-walking interpreter. *All* modern Ruby implementations are compiled.

Comment: Awesome answer 

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Fun question and good answer. I don't think your comment is helpful @Jorg, it's a start of a huge debate and not really addressing the point.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @JörgWMittag here - I am usually the first one to correct "interpreted language" phrase and here I've used it here by myself! I tried to make it as simple as possible, but as a result might have spread a bit of misinformation... In any case - Ruby is compiled into AST, however interpreter still interprets that AST at runtime. AST does not hold references to methods or variables, but just tokens and arguments in form of a tree - tokens has to be resolved via the lookup process. It is a price of Ruby being highly dynamic language

Answer (score 1):

I'm going far on a limb here (for fun mostly) and guessing you do something like this

```
>> pp "this is a test"
"this is a test"
=> "this is a test"
>> pp = pp
=> nil
>> pp pp
nil
=> nil
>> pp "this is another test"
"this is another test"
=> "this is another test"
```

So here's what happens

```
pp = pp
```

You've created a local variable `pp` which got assigned a value of whatever `pp` method returned (`nil` in this case)

```
>> pp pp
```

here you call `pp` method and passing it `pp` variable, which holds `nil`

```
>> pp "this is another test"
"this is another test"
=> "this is another test"
```

you still can call `pp` method as usually.

Not sure why would you expect it to loop. Expressions are evaluated (right to left in general), so they will evaluate eventually. No infinite loops should generally happen. Take this example:

```
x = y = z = x
```

It will first evaluate right-most `x` (which has not been defined, so defaults to `nil`, so next step conceptually will be:

```
x = y = z = nil
```

assigns nil to z, and result of this evaluation is also nil

```
x = y = nil
```

assigns nil to y
and so on...

Comment: Your second example is evaluated more like this: `x = nil; y = nil; z = nil; x = y = z = x`, but the end result is the same.

Comment: "No infinite loops should generally happen" - except for when there's infinite recursion, of course. I'm guessing, that's what the OP expected to happen here, but why - that I have no idea about.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this can be better shown in the example `a = b = c`. This results in a `NameError` however `a #=> nil` and `b #=> nil`.